Error with libcurl.so.4 undefined reference to __fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15 during Conda environment compilation
I'm compiling a C++/MPICXX software program within a Conda environment that includes the following requirements (the version I currently have):
cmake (3.26.3)
openmpi (4.1.6)
h5pcc [mpi_openmpi_h457a7a6_3] (1.14.0) 
GCC and g++ compilers (14.2.0)

My compute node has the following OS:
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-x.x.x.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64

I am specifically using the following CMake command for compilation:
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/mpicc \
          -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/mpicxx \
          -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX \
          -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/include \
          -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib \
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$CONDA_PREFIX \

However, I get the following error during compilation/linking:
$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/./
libcurl.so.4: undefined reference to `__fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15'
libcurl.so.4: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
libcurl.so.4: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'

What I've already done were:

Verified the GLIBC version (my system's GLIBC version is 2.17), and I also verified that the Conda libc.so.6 is located at $CONDA_PREFIX/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib64/libc.so.6.

Installed libcurl (8.2.1) within the Conda environment.

Attempted to manually add -lrt to linker flags but received the same error.

Used the Conda environment ld (2.43) version compared to the system's /usr/bin/ld (version 2.27).


What could be causing these undefined reference errors with GLIBC symbols like __fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15, and how can I resolve them within my Conda environment?

I just solved this problem tonight after 3 days of having a headache lol! The issue was that the linker ld being used was in /usr/bin instead of the $CONDA_PREFIX/bin. To avoid any dependency mix-ups, I realized I needed to reinstall everything from scratch.
Here’s what I did:

Create a new conda environment named my_env with python=3.9
Install the necessary prerequisites for the program:
conda install -y hdf5=*=mpi* gcc gxx openmpi cmake -c conda-forge. This should install the dependencies for the parallel version of HDF5, OpenMPI, and MPICXX. Note that the HDF5 in conda lis should refer to openmpi or mpi. This should also download the appropriate GLIBC for the said packages.
Verify that the $CONDA_PREFIX/lib and $CONDA_PREFIX/include directories contained libmpi.so and libhdf5.so, respectively. You can refer to the CMakeLists.txt for the exact file path for verification.

P.S. I tried a similar approach last time but with a different installation order (i.e., placing hdf5=*=mpi* at the end or installing gcc/gxx separately). For future reference, I recommend downloading all dependencies together and using the same channel to avoid any library mix-ups.
